# Which is correct $form_state['values'] or $form_state['input']?

Tags: forms, drupal-7

I used ajax to populate dependent fields and rebuild the field structure but in this whole process `$form_state['values']` get erased but `$form_state['input']` keeps the values through out the process and functionality works properly using `$form_state['input']`.

I am working on contribute module and while doing review using pareview.sh it suggest me to use `$form_state['values']` instead of `$form_state['input']`. But in most of the scenarios I didn't get required values in `$form_state['values']`.

Please suggest me what should I do to resolved those warnings in pareview.sh?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all the values get submitted by the form are stored inside `$form_state['values']` array.

Try using `var_dump($form_state['values']);` to get an idea of what fields are getting submitted.

Comment: Hi Muhammad thanks for your comment, but I am using ajax in my form to re populate some fields and when I submit the form $from_state['values'] looses the fields those are populated using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here for more informations about form state keys -> https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410

To keep simple

$form_state['values'] // POST sanitized data

$form_state['input'] // POST raw data

There is a discussion here : https://www.drupal.org/node/1250172

Do you implement your ajax call with form api ?

Comment: Yes I used ajax call with form api to generate new fields on the basis of previous field selection and also used 'managed_file' which also uses the ajax call to upload file.